# Using Datastax DevCenter with Apigee Cassandra

Tags: apigee

How do I connect to the Apigee Cassandra using DataStax DevCenter?

Long story, but we want to connect remotely.  Really.

I saw some notes saying that we need to set some values in cassandra.yaml

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
```

Also, is the Login and password a UNIX account?

any help on what you have filling out the Connection Manager and the cassandra.yaml would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Connecting Datastax to Apigee Cassandra is not supported at this time.

Comment: Isn't that like having an Oracle database as part of your application and saying you do not support Toad? How can it not work?  Isn't it just a client like the Management server is a client and connects to C*?

Comment: We are not setup to allow direct access to the Cassandra database at this time.  What in particular are you trying to do?